# Como atualizar um JTextArea com informações de JCheckBoxes?

Tags: java, swing

Estou a precisar de ajuda no seguinte, eu tenho uma janela que o utilizador pode ativar os JCheckBoxes para escrever na JTextArea que se situa abaixo, como a seguinte imagem:

[image: Frame do meu programa]

O que eu queria é que quando se pressionasse a JCheckBox do Teclado aparecesse uma mensagem a dizer "o teclado esta danificado" e se eu retirasse o check do JCheckBox não aparecesse nada em baixo, Como por exemplo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu já consegui fazer foi por o JCheckBox a escrever o que pretendo,mas quero que ele atualize e quando eu pressionar o JCheckBox apareça na JTextArea e quando eu tirar o "certo" do JCheckBox eliminasse o que tinha sido escrito que era "o teclado esta danificado" queria só dizer que os JCheckBox´s não são a única coisa que tenho no programa,ou seja,além de nesse JTextArea ser mostrado o conteúdo das ações  JCheckBox´s é mostrado algumas notas que serão feitas na frame seguinte,ou seja, eu queria que uma linha seja para

> 1-"o teclado esta danificado"
>   2-"o rato esta danificado"
>   3-"o monitor esta danificado"
>   4-"o torre esta danificado"
>
> ### 5 e outra para os detalhes

Isto tudo está escrito para guardar em um documento .txt.

```
private JPanel contentPane;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                Aluno7_Ruben frame = new Aluno7_Ruben();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public Aluno7_Ruben() {
    setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("C:\\Users\\Jo\u00E3o Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\icon\\Science-Classroom-icon.png"));

    setTitle("PC7-Ruben Gato");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    setContentPane(contentPane);
    contentPane.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblNewLabel = new JLabel("Detalhes/Notas:");
    lblNewLabel.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    lblNewLabel.setBounds(10, 106, 194, 23);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel);

    JLabel lblNewLabel_1 = new JLabel("Localiza\u00E7\u00E3o da avaria:");
    lblNewLabel_1.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    lblNewLabel_1.setBounds(10, 11, 169, 20);
    contentPane.add(lblNewLabel_1);

    JCheckBox Teclado = new JCheckBox ("Teclado");
    Teclado.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            PrintWriter writer;
            try {
                String texto1="O teclado esta danificado";
                writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt");
                writer.println(texto1 );

                writer.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    });
    Teclado.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
    Teclado.setBounds(6, 54, 94, 23);
    contentPane.add(Teclado);

    JCheckBox  Rato = new JCheckBox ("Rato");
    Rato.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
    Rato.setBounds(98, 54, 81, 23);
    contentPane.add(Rato);

    JCheckBox  Monitor = new JCheckBox ("Monitor");
    Monitor.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
    Monitor.setBounds(190, 54, 96, 23);
    contentPane.add(Monitor);

    JCheckBox Torre = new JCheckBox ("Torre");
    Torre.setToolTipText("Selecionar caso esteja danificado");
    Torre.setBounds(288, 54, 109, 23);
    contentPane.add(Torre);

    JButton Adicionar_notas = new JButton("Escrever novas notas");
    Adicionar_notas.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
            FAZJA(evt);
        }
    });

    Adicionar_notas.setBounds(137, 224, 159, 23);
    contentPane.add(Adicionar_notas);

    File file = new File("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    String texto = "";

    try {
        fis = new FileInputStream(file);
        int content;
        while ((content = fis.read()) != -1) {
            texto += (char) content;
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (fis != null) {
                fis.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    JTextArea textArea1 = new JTextArea(texto);

    textArea1.setEditable(false);
    textArea1.setWrapStyleWord(true);
    textArea1.setBounds(10, 128, 414, 85);
    contentPane.add(textArea1); 
}

protected void FAZJA(ActionEvent evt) {
    this.dispose();
    new Gravação_Dados().setVisible(true);
}
```

Aqui está o código desta frame. Estava a fazer as experiências no JCheckBox do teclado mas não consegui. Preciso mesmo de ajuda não encontro nada em lado nenhum.

Comment: desculpe mas para alem de editar sabe como se resolve o meu problema ?

Comment: João, tentou passar o valor de `texto1` direto para o `textArea1`? Assim: `textArea1.append(texto1);`?

Comment: Se for fazer como falei, o melhor seria instanciar o `texto`, e todo o seu carregamento, e o `textArea1` no começo da classe.

Comment: Não ainda não tentei,vou tentar, obrigado pela sugestão! Se não conseguir já tenho uma ideia como irei fazer

Comment: Eu acabei pegando os seus codigos e criando uma replica funcional aqui no meu. Teria mais alguns pontos para se levar em consideração, por isso vou colocar uma resposta, @Joao.

Answer (score 2):

Como havia dito, no método `listener` o correto seria acrescentar o valor de `texto1` em `textArea1`, ficando algo parecido com isso:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    Writer writer;
        try {
            String texto1 = "O Teclado esta danificado";
            writer = new PrintWriter(
                "C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt");
            writer.println(texto1);
            textArea1.append(texto1+"\n");
            writer.close();
        } catch (IOException e1) {
        }
    }
}
```

Encontrei um problema a partir daqui... A classe Writer não estava acrescentando, mas sim substituindo o valor da primeira linha e não colocava mais nada a partir dai.
A minha solução encontrada foi substituir `Writer` por `BufferedWriter`, pois o `BufferedWriter` funciona como quero, além de ter as funções `append()` e `newLine()`, onde fazem, respectivamente, concatenar uma string ao valor original, e inserir uma quebra de linha no código, ficando mais ou menos assim as partes carentes de mudanças:

```
BufferedWriter writer;
writer = new BufferedWriter(
    new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\João Gil\\workspace\\sala de aula\\pic\\notas.txt", true));
```

A partir daqui, estava funcionando quase que corretamente. A única parte que enxergava ao contrario era que ele escrevia no arquivo mesmo se a seleção fosse `false`, o checkBox fosse desselecionado. Então coloquei toda a parte do `try...catch` dentro de um if, que checava o valor booleano de seleção, ficando assim:

```
if (Objeto.isSelected()){
    try {
        //Conteudo
    } catch (IOException e1) {
    }
}
```

Comment: muito obrigado mesmo!

Comment: tive a ver e a por a sua sugestão o problema e que agr ele nao grava como devia gravar

Comment: Hm... e como está salvando?

Comment: não esta a gravar sequer

Comment: Hm... isso é estranho... A iniciação dos componentes `File file`, `String texto`, e `JTextArea textArea1` estão logo abaixo da inicialização do `contentPane`?

Comment: vou fazer o seguinte posso editar a minha duvida para colocar o codigo que ja tenho para lhe mostrar?

Comment: Pode claro, mas desde que não fuja da pergunta inicial.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no bate-papo](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/18970/discussion-between-joao-gil-and-gustavo-cinque).